# 3rd row of system tray not visible if I'm not looking at display tab of Settings application in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notification-area, display-settings

Now this is extremely weird for me. I've three rows in my system tray. I'm on Windows 10 machine (Dual monitor) with below system information:

**OS Name** : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

**Version** 10.0.17134 Build 17134

The problem is that I see only top two rows of system tray as shown below:

[image]

Now how do I know that there are three rows? Have a look at the screenshot below. The tool tip for Outlook application present in 3rd row is shown but the icon is hidden.

[image]

Now here is the magic part. Open Settings application and go to `Display` tab. Now I see all three rows:

[image]

Even if I select a different tab (e.g. `Sound`) in Settings application, the third row becomes hidden again as shown below:

[image]

What can I do to resolve this. I need all three rows in the system tray to be displayed always no matter which application I'm looking at.

**Update**: The setting `Always show all icons in the notification area` is set to off on my PC:

[image]

Comment: It is not a row that is missing, but 3 of the icons, so that the remaining ones fit into two rows. Have you set "Always show all icons in the notification area", or are all the individual icons set to appear?

Comment: The `Always show all icons in the notification area` setting is currently set to `off` on my PC.

Comment: Setting it to `on` should resolve your problem. Notice that Chrome is set not to display icon in notification area, and this is one of the missing icons.

Comment: Yes. It does solve the problem but then a quarter of my task bar is filled with system tray icons only leaving very less space for currently running application. There are over 2 dozen icons in my system tray including date time.

Comment: Then you'll need to choose which ones you want to appear with the individual settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue after a computer restart which was required as I had installed SQL Server Management Studio. This is not a real solution but you can give it a try if it works for you. I hope some real solution will come later from community.

[image]

One thing I definitely suspect is that this issue happens in first place whenever I connect my PC remotely through MSTSC application from one of the meetings rooms in my company. There are big TV screens connected to computers kept in meeting rooms which we use to launch MSTSC. Somehow, the display scaling, layout or resolution gets messed up when I project my computer on such a big screen and then later return to a dual monitor projection.